# The NextPage cannot retrieve user data, why?

Tags: jsp

JSP stars I'm having a problem that seems to be beyond my knowledge as I'm very new to JSP though with some basic knowledge of JAVA.Some one on the Forum tried to provide me with a few details that helped me to eliminate the error message page, but did not complete helping me to solve the whole problem. For testing purposes when I try to input user data in the form.jsp and click on Submit button and then 'continue' link on SaveName.jsp, I'm directed to the NextPage.jsp where I expect to retrieve data, unfortunately there is no input data displayed on the page. Why ? Can some one come to my rescue please !

```
Example: (form.jsp)   
Username field: Denis(input data)  
e-mail(field): byansimedia@gmail.com(input data)  
Age (field): 30(input data)
```

This is what I get on the NextPage.jsp:

```
You entered:
Name:  
Email: 
Age:
```

I can't retrieve the input data - why and how can I sort it out ?

Below are the JDK path; CLASSPATH: .jsp files and java bean.
CLASSPATH: **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;**
Path: **C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;**
JAVA_HOME:**C:\glassfish3\jdk**

`<HTML>

    <BODY>

    <FORM METHOD = POST ACTION = "SaveName.jsp">

    What's your name ? <INPUT TYPE = TEXT NAME = username SIZE = 20 > <BR>

    What's your e-mail?<INPUT TYPE = TEXT NAME = email SIZE = 20 > <BR>

    What's your age ?  <INPUT TYPE = TEXT NAME = age SIZE = 4 >

    <P> <INPUT TYPE = SUBMIT >

    </FORM>

    </BODY>

    </HTML>`
form.jsp

`<jsp : useBean id = "user" class="user.UserData" scope="session"/>

    <jsp : setProperty name = "user" property = "*"/>

    <HTML>

    <BODY>

    <A HREF="NextPage.jsp">Continue</A>

    </BODY>

    </HTML>`

SaveName.jsp

```
<jsp : useBean id = "user" class = "user.UserData" scope = "session"/>
<HTML>
<BODY>
You entered<BR>
Name: ${user.username } <BR />
Email: ${user.email } <BR />
Age: ${user.age } <BR />
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

NextPage.jsp

I have saved the three files above in the following root path:
 **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\jsp pages**

```
 package user;
    public class UserData 
    {

String username;
String email;
int age;

public void setUsername ( String value)

{
username=value;

}

public void setEmail ( String value)

{
email=value;

}

public void setAge ( int value)
{
age=value;

}

public String getUsername() 
{
return username;
}

public String getEmail()
{
return email;
}

public int getAge()
{
return age;
}

}
```

UserData.java compiled into UserData.class

I have saved the above java bean (.java and .class files) in the root folder below, though I just created the classes folder as it did not exist.
**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\user**

Comment: When you submit a form, the form data does not instantly go into the session object.  You have to read it from the request object, sanitize it, and save it in the session (if that's what you want) or in the db.

Comment: `jsp : useBean` should be `jsp:useBean`. Same for `jsp:setProperty`. That said, you should forget immediaely about this way of doing things. Parameters need to be validated. Learn about the MVC architecture.

Comment: @developerwjk thanks so much... I can get your point. If I don't use the java bean I can retrieve the data. That means I should focus on DB as I have also basic knowledge of it.

Comment: @ JB Nizet thanks.. I tried to eliminate the space in between the two codes / syntax however it generates an error message. I have rushed through the MVC article, though it's my first time I could grasp what it is all about. I have got a feeling it's similar to what @developerwjk was refering me to. I guess the DB option is much better for me with some basic formal knowledge.